# What is PIPESTATUS=([0]="0")?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

well thank you I appreciate it. That works well Ill consider that for sure. And your right post was all over the place. Thanks for the instruction. If have any more questions ill post them.

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` is *not* an environment variable; it's a shell builtin not exported to the environment.

Comment: BTW, there's a lot you're adding to your question here that isn't really relevant or useful. You might consider accepting the third-party edits that try to remove things not appropriate to the gist rather than rolling them back or recreating content.

Comment: ...or, rather -- if all the stuff you edited in _after_ the cleanup provided by @tripleee is supposed to be relevant, then your question is a candidate for being closed as overbroad. Keep it simple and to the point; there's no need for rambling.

Comment: ... Or maybe just "Unclear what you're asking."

Comment: My question is how does one get a pf PIPESTATUS=([0]="100")

Comment: Lessopen and Lessclose determine the Pipestatus correct? My Flags simply were set piped to less which is usually do something like :~$ set | less | (cat >> MyEnv.txt) but my machine was humming so i didnt. I just ran a few ps and lsof on my processes and then checked my systems environment.

Comment: @geoffW, that's your only question? `sh -c 'exit 100'` will do it; it's a single command (thus, the single-command pipeline case anticipated by the description), and its exit status is 100. **Any** single command with an exit status of 100 would have that same effect.

Comment: ...and no, lessopen and lessclose have nothing whatsoever to do with PIPESTATUS. @EtanReisner's answer includes everything you need to know to understand it.

Comment: PTYs, tilde expansion, and all the other stuff you've been going on about have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Charles you're are correct! Even though there isn't a bourne (sh) shell on Ubuntu, the sh is a symbolic link between Bash and Dash (Debian ash). It basically simulates a finite state automation in the historical diamond pattern of data flow. Just exporting PIPESTATUS=([0]="100") would be sufficient, I didn't do either one of those. I was just removing applications I never use from the system, with apt-get --purge remove and was wondering which app and why does it have that upon removal

Comment: You would have been able to see that if someone else hadn't edited my post while i was at the veternarian's office with my dog. Which I found that be odd, odd indeed. I also find it odd that I deleted a post a week ago , and couldn't delete this one. Which tells me there is not uniform policy on this site.

Comment: Removing all the content of the original post and leaving only this "thank you" message was a really BAD idea.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for `PIPESTATUS` is available in the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

> PIPESTATUS
>
> An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Answer (score 1):

```
true | false | true
declare -p PIPESTATUS
```

Output:

```
declare -a PIPESTATUS='([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="0")'
```